# How to Generate Leave Balance Table for a particular employee using Laravel

Tags: laravel

In my Laravel-5.8 project, when an employee logs in I want to display a table as shown below that shows his Leave Balance

[image: leave balance]

I have 3 tables that are applicable

```
class LeaveCategory extends Model
{
   protected $table = 'leave_categories';

   protected $fillable = [
              'leave_category_name',
          ];

   public function leavecategorydetail()
   {
       return $this->hasMany('App\Models\LeaveCategoryDetail');
   }  
}

class LeaveCategoryDetail extends Model
{
   protected $table = 'leave_category_details';
   protected $fillable = [
              'id',
              'leave_category_id',
              'employment_type_id',
              'no_of_days',
          ];

   public function leavecategory()
   {
       return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\LeaveCategory', 'leave_category_id', 'id');
   }

   public function employmenttype()
   {
       return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\EmploymentType', 'employment_type_id', 'id' );
   }    
}

class LeaveRequest extends Model
{
   protected $table = 'leave_requests';
   protected $fillable = [
              'id',
              'employee_id',
              'leave_category_id',
              'leave_status',
              'approved_days',
          ];


   public function employee()
   {
       return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Employee','employee_id');
   }    

   public function leavetype()
   {
       return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\LeaveCategory','leave_category_id');
   }
}
```

As earlier said, the expected result is to have 4 columns (Leave Category
, Applicable Leave, Approved Leave
, Available
)

Controller

```
public function leave_balance()
{
    $userId = Auth::user()->id;
$userCompany = Auth::user()->company_id;
$employmentcategory = Employee::select('employeement_category_id')->where('employee_id', $userId)->where('is_active', 1)->first();

//Leave Category
$leavecategories = LeaveCategory::select('leave_category_name')->where('company_id', $userCompany)->get();

//Applicable Leave
    $applicableleaves = DB::table('leave_categories')
             ->join('leave_category_details', 'leave_category_details.leave_category_id', '=', 'leave_categories.id')
             ->select('leave_category_details.no_of_days')
             ->where('leave_categories.company_id', $userCompany)
             ->where('leave_categories.employment_category_id',$employmentcategory)
             ->get(); 

//Approved Leave
    $approvedleaves = DB::table('leave_requests')
             ->select('employee_id','leave_category_id', DB::raw('SUM(approved_days) AS approvedLeave'))
             ->where('employee_id', $userId)
     ->where('leave_category_id', $employmentcategory)
             ->where('leave_status',4)
             ->groupBy('employee_id', 'leave_category_id')
             ->get(); 

//Available
$availableleaves = $applicableleaves - $approvedleaves

   $leavebalances = ...

return view('leave-balances')
    ->with('leavebalances', $leavebalances)
}
```

How do I combine the four queries in my controller ($leavecategories, $applicableleaves, $approvedleaves, $availableleaves) into $leavebalances and also get a view like

> See the leave balance image

```
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th width="55%">
                        Leave Category
                    </th>
                    <th width="15%">
                        Applicable Leave
                    </th>
                    <th width="15%">
                        Approved Leave
                    </th>
                    <th width="15%">
                        leavebalances
                    </th>                        
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>      
                <!--start foreach-->
                    <td>

                    </td> 
                    <td>

                    </td>      
                    <td>

                    </td> 
                    <td>

                    </td>                           
                <!--end foreach-->
```

> If there is no field/value for $approvedleaves, it should initialize with 0

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Why get each column in a separate query when you can get them all in one.

I adjusted your controller like so:

```
public function leave_balance()
{
    $userId = Auth::user()->id;
        $userCompany = Auth::user()->company_id;
        $employmentCategoryId = Employee::where('employee_id', $userId)->where('is_active', 1)->value('employeement_category_id');

        //Leave Table
         $leaveTable = DB::table('leave_categories as lc')
            ->join('leave_category_details as lcd', 'lcd.leave_category_id', '=', 'lc.id')
            ->join('leave_requests as lr', 'lr.leave_category_id', '=', 'lc.id')
            ->select('lcd.no_of_days as applicableLeaves ','lc.leave_category_name as leaveCategory',DB::raw('SUM(lr.approved_days) AS approvedLeaves'))
            ->where([
                ['lc.company_id', $userCompany],
                ['lc.employment_category_id',$employmentCategoryId],
                ['lr.employee_id', $userId],
                ['lr.leave_status',4]
            ])
            ->groupBy('leaveCategory', 'applicableLeaves')
            ->get();


return view('leave-balances')
    ->with('leaveTable', $leaveTable)
}
```

`$availableleaves` can be calculated in the view no need to send it.

Now in your view you display them like this:

```
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th width="55%">
                    Leave Category
                </th>
                <th width="15%">
                    Applicable Leave
                </th>
                <th width="15%">
                    Approved Leave
                </th>
                <th width="15%">
                    leavebalances
                </th>                        
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>      
            @foreach ($leaveTable as $tableRow)
             <tr>
                <td>
                 {{$tableRow->leaveCategory}}
                </td> 
                <td>
                 {{$tableRow->applicableLeaves}}
                </td>      
                <td>
                 @if(!$tabelRow->approvedLeaves->isEmpty()){{$tabelRow->approvedLeaves}}@else 0 @endif
                </td> 
                <td>
                 {{($tableRow->applicableLeaves - $tabelRow->approvedLeaves)}}
                </td>   
            </tr>                        
             @endforeach
       </tbody>
```

HTML is not my strongest field so your table might not show as wanted but i think its all good.

Comment: When there is no record in leave_requests, its not showing anything. As I stated in the question, I still want it to display the records: show leave_categories, applicablesLeave, and put 0 in the ones not available.  Thank you

Comment: Edited, now it should show 0 when no `$approvedLeave` is present

Comment: It still did not displayed anything. At least, LeaveCategories, ApplicableLeaves will always have data.

Comment: Edited again to `isEmpty()` to check, now if the `$leaveTable` data is correct but the view is not showing it the right way you can ask a new question, i'm sure people with more *view experience* will be glad to help.

Comment: It's still the same thing. No data at all in the table. Is there a way to write the code from the controller to resove that. To every load  At least, LeaveCategories, ApplicableLeaves will always have data. O to use left join.  Thanks

Comment: You can try to replace the regulare `join` with a `leftJoin` on leave_requests `leftJoin('leave_requests as lr', 'lr.leave_category_id', '=', 'lc.id')`.

Answer (score 0):

bro you can try make the two querys in one like this is not perfect but you get the idea

```
$all = DB::table('leave_category_details')
->leftJoin('leave_categories', function($join)
{
    $join->on('leave_categories.id', '=', 'leave_category_details.leave_category_id');
    $join->on('leave_categories.employment_category_id',$employmentcategory);
    $join->on('leave_categories.company_id','=', $userCompany);

})
->leftJoin('leave_requests', function($join)
{
    $join->on('leave_requests.employee_id', '=', $userId);
    $join->on('leave_requests.leave_category_id', $employmentcategory);
    $join->on('leave_status',4);

})
->groupBy('leave_requests.employee_id', 'leave_requests.leave_category_id')

->select('leave_category_details.no_of_days','leave_requests.employee_id','leave_requests.leave_category_id', DB::raw('SUM(leave_requests.approved_days) AS approvedLeave'),DB::raw('SUM(leave_requests.approved_days) - leave_category_details.no_of_days  AS availableleaves')
->get();
```

Comment: I got this error:  [2020-05-19 11:43:11] production.ERROR: Undefined variable: employmentcategory {"userId":2,"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0). Why. The variable is declared